# Symfony Upgrade from 3.2 to 3.3 : TraceableAdapter

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.2, symfony-3.3

I have upgraded Symfony from 3.2 to 3.3. I have readed this : https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/UPGRADE-3.3.md

But now, I have this error :

> Type error: Argument 2 passed to AppBundle\EventListener\ForumListener::__construct() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\FilesystemAdapter, instance of Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\TraceableAdapter given, called in /var/www/symfony/WikiSport/var/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 612

I don't understand because in UPGRADE-3.3.md, There is no information for FilesystemAdapter or TraceableAdapter.

**ForumListener.php :**

```
use Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\FilesystemAdapter;

class ForumListener
{
    private $cache;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager, FilesystemAdapter $cache)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->cache = $cache;
    }
```

**And services.yml :**

```
app.forum_listener:
    class: AppBundle\EventListener\ForumListener
    autowire: true
    public: true
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.controller, method: onKernelController }
```

Can you help me ? Thank you very much :)

Comment: Autowire still has a few kinks to work out.  Easiest approach is to just go back to manual wiring.  Otherwise, dig into the new container docs.  Also wondering if there is a cache interface?  Just using the interface in your listener might do the trick.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?